# cookie expire on click of button

Tags: php, function, session, setcookie

Can we add events to php.
Just as i want to log out ie. destroy my current session and delete the existing cookie on click of a button.
The button form action corresponds to same page drum.php

```
<?php
$h=0;
if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {
  if($h==0) {
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
      $_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
    } else {
      $_SESSION['views']=1;
    }
    echo "You have been logged in as: ".$_COOKIE["name"].".Your session will expire in "."5min."."You have viewed this page ".$_SESSION['views'];
  } else {
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("name",$name,time()-25);
  }
} else {
  echo "<form action='drum.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='name'></input>          `   </input><input type='submit' value='Log in'></input></form>";
  $name=$_POST["name"];
  $expire=time()+2*60;
  setcookie("name",$name,$expire);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. At the start of the PHP page, write `if(isset($_POST['buttonName']))` and then nest all your actions for that button within that. And make sure your form posts to that page itself.

Every time the page's requested, it checks whether the button has been clicked and logs out if true. If false, it shows the regular content.

Comment: Just adding: for this to work the button must submit the form (which is the case here), else you need to fire an AJAX request from the button's onclick handler (the php part works the same way, just the method of triggering it is different)